# C2061 syntax error: identifier 'LPWNDCLASSEXA'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2019

*I am getting below error*

> *C2061    syntax error: identifier 'LPWNDCLASSEXA' in file*
> *c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\WinUser.h*

I am porting a VS-2012 code to VS-2019. The code compiles well on VS-2012. When I open the solution file in VS-2019, It gives a choice to upgrade Windows SDK Kit and Platform ToolChain [image: Update ToolChain]. I choose to upgrade. But now its getting failed in compilation.
There was other errors as well which were fixed after I install  142 build tools  via Visual Studio Installer.

Now I am getting below error

```
> C2061 syntax error: identifier 'LPWNDCLASSEXA' in file
> c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\WinUser.h

I also tried to get include hierarchy which is as:

Rebuild started...
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: handler-messages, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>cl : command line warning D9035: option 'Gm' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
1>dllmain.cpp
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\windows.h
1>Note: including file:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\winapifamily.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\winpackagefamily.h
1>Note: including file:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\sdkddkver.h
1>Note: including file:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\excpt.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vcruntime.h
1>Note: including file:    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\sal.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\concurrencysal.h
1>Note: including file:    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vadefs.h
1>Note: including file:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\stdarg.h
1>Note: including file:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\windef.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\minwindef.h
1>Note: including file:    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\specstrings.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\specstrings_strict.h
1>Note: including file:      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\specstrings_undef.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\driverspecs.h
1>Note: including file:      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\sdv_driverspecs.h
1>Note: including file:    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\winnt.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\ctype.h
1>Note: including file:      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt.h
1>Note: including file:      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_wctype.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\kernelspecs.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\basetsd.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\guiddef.h
1>Note: including file:      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\string.h
1>Note: including file:       C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_memory.h
1>Note: including file:        C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_memcpy_s.h
1>Note: including file:         C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\errno.h
1>Note: including file:         C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vcruntime_string.h
1>Note: including file:       C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstring.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\pshpack4.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\poppack.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\pshpack4.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\poppack.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\pshpack4.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\poppack.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\pshpack4.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\pshpack2.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\poppack.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\pshpack2.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\pshpack2.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\poppack.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\poppack.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\pshpack8.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\poppack.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\pshpack1.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\poppack.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\pshpack1.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\poppack.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\poppack.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\apiset.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\ktmtypes.h
1>Note: including file:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\winbase.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\apisetcconv.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\minwinbase.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\apiquery2.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\processenv.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\fileapifromapp.h
1>Note: including file:    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\fileapi.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\debugapi.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\utilapiset.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\handleapi.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\errhandlingapi.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\fibersapi.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\namedpipeapi.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\profileapi.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\heapapi.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\ioapiset.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\synchapi.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\interlockedapi.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\processthreadsapi.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\sysinfoapi.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\memoryapi.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\enclaveapi.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\threadpoollegacyapiset.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\threadpoolapiset.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\jobapi.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\jobapi2.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\wow64apiset.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\libloaderapi.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\securitybaseapi.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\namespaceapi.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\systemtopologyapi.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\processtopologyapi.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\securityappcontainer.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\realtimeapiset.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\winerror.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\timezoneapi.h
1>Note: including file:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\wingdi.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\pshpack1.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\poppack.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\pshpack2.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\poppack.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\pshpack2.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\poppack.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\pshpack4.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\poppack.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\pshpack4.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\poppack.h
1>Note: including file:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\winuser.h
**1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\winuser.h(4380,11): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'LPWNDCLASSEXA'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\winuser.h(4388,11): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'LPWNDCLASSEXW'**
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\pshpack2.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\poppack.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\tvout.h
1>Note: including file:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\winnls.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\datetimeapi.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\stringapiset.h
1>Note: including file:    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\winnls.h
1>Note: including file:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\wincon.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\wincontypes.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\consoleapi.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\consoleapi2.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\consoleapi3.h
1>Note: including file:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\winver.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\verrsrc.h
1>Note: including file:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\winreg.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\reason.h
1>Note: including file:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\winnetwk.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\wnnc.h
1>Note: including file:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\stralign.h
1>Note: including file:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\winsvc.h
1>Done building project "handler-messages.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Show the code that you compile.

Comment: These things (LPWNDCLASSEXA and LPWNDCLASSEXW) is there since at least 1998 and haven't changed since then.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/porting/port-migrate-and-upgrade-visual-studio-projects?view=vs-2019&preserve-view=true) for porting projects.

Using LPWNDCLASSEXA needs to add #include<Windows.h>, try to add it and run the code.

Answer (score 0):

I have to downgrade the Windows SDK version to 10.0.17763.0 from 10.0.19041.0

It might seems weird but as per my investigation WinUser.h has mismatch for #if and #endif directives. I might be wrong and didn't go much deeper into investigation.

Comment: But there should be a way to it without downgrading, otherwise you should use a different compiler.